# Laplace equation in exterior domain of a disk

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation in 2 dimension case ,$\Delta u(x_1,x_2)=0$ ,$u=1$ for $|x|=1$, and $u \rightarrow 0$ as $|x|$ tends to $\infty$.

Do we have a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Let's asume that a solution exists and
consider the conformal transformation 
$$(y_1,y_2) = \frac{(x_1,-x_2)}{x_1^2 + x_2^2},$$
that maps the exterior of the disk to the interior, and consider the new function 
$$v(x_1,x_2) = u(y_1,y_2).$$
Because the transformation is conformal, and $u$ is harmonic, then $v$ is harmonic as well. So
$$ \Delta v = 0 \quad  \forall|x|\leq 1,$$
$$ v = 1 \quad \forall|x|= 1,$$
and the condition at infinity translate into $v(0,0) = 0$. But using the mean value property for $v$
$$v(0,0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|x| = 1} v(x) dx = 1,$$
which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation in polar coordinates. Since the boundary value at $|x|=1$ has circular symmetry, look for a solution depending only on $r$.

Comment: Yes, but if we consider the equation $\Delta u_R(x_1,x_2)=0$ ,$u_R=1$ for $|x|=1$, and $u_R = 0$ if $|x|=R$, we have $u=C\log(|x|/R)$, what happen if we let $R \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: The general solution is $u=A\log r+B$. There are no bounded solutions.

Comment: So,there is no solution for my question?

Comment: No such solution exists.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre This only proof that there are not bounded solution with radial symmetry.